# What's the name of this algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Recently I was reading the errata for J.Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* , and I encountered an interesting algorithm (used in a lemma for Theorem 17.32 in [this pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/errata.pdf))) Unfortunately I know nothing about algorithms, so I would appreciate it if someone tells me the name of this algorithm.

---

From now on, we will fix an arbitrary symmetric relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

A few terminology: (I improvised them, so it might be different from the standard usage; forgive me in that case.)

- Let $A\subset \mathbb {N}$. Then:

  - The  elements  in $A$ are called its **vertices**;
  - We say that two vertices $v,w\in A$ are **associated in $A$** (or $v$ is **associated with $w$ in $A$**) if there is a  finite sequence $v_1,\cdots ,v_n\in A$ such that $v=v_1$, $w=v_n$, and $(v_j, v_{j+1})\in R$ for each $j$.
  - We say $A$ is **connected** if every pair of vertices in $A$ are associated in $A$. A maximal connected subset of $A$ is called the **component** of $A$
    The algorithm concerns with the following problem.

> Suppose that $\mathbb {N}$ is connected, and suppose that for each
>   $v\in \mathbb N$,  there exist at least one, but only finitely many,
>   vertices $w\neq v$ such that $(v,w)\in R$. Then there is a partition
>   $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ into connected subsets, satisfying the following properties:
>
> - Each $A_j$ is finite.
> - For each $j$, there is some $k>j$ such that there are $v_j\in A_j$ and  $v_k\in A_k$ with $(v_j,v_k)\in R$ .

The algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. We set $A_0=\emptyset$ for convinience.
2. Supposing that $A_0,\cdots, A_{n-1}$ are defined, we define $A_{n}$ to be the union of $\{m\}$ and  all the  finite components of $\mathbb N\setminus (\bigcup_{i<n}A_i \cup \{m\})$, where $m= \min \left(\mathbb N\setminus (\bigcup_{i<n}A_i )\right)$.
3. Voila! The resulting sequence $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ has the desired properties!

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m confused: if $\mathbb N$ is connected then every pair of vertices in $\mathbb N$ are associated.  Then how can there be only finitely many vertices associated with some $v$?  I must be missing something quite basic.

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you for pointing out the error. Now I fixed it.

Comment: @Rahul Oh, yes, thank you for pointing that out. I think I was confused when I edited it. I fixed it.

Comment: Things are still a bit weird. Assuming $\mathbb N$ is connected means that the second condition only requires each $A_j$ to be nonempty and then already $A_{j+1}$ will contain a vertex associated with a vertex in $A_j$ (because any two vertices are associated). Maybe, once again, the second condition wants $v_j \in A_j, v_k \in A_k$ with $(v_j, v_k) \in R$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes. I am sorry for my mistake...